# How to remove weak reference from object? in Swift

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, weak-references

I have a class which is named `ChatDataSource`. The `ChatDataSource` has a `ChatManager` class like lazy var. If a user will not do any action `ChatManager` will not to init. `ChatManager` has some blocks which are calling some functions from `ChatDataSource`. I made in closers weak references for `ChatDataSource`. I noticed that `ChatDataSource` object never deinit from memory because the `ChatManager` keeps him weak link. The problem also lies in the fact that when I open a new conversation and init a new `ChatDataSource`, the old `ChatDataSource` is in memory. `ChatManager` also lives in other controllers. How can I remove a weak refence from ChatManager?

A snippet of my code

```
class ChatDataSource: ChatDataSourceProtocol {

       fileprivate lazy var chatManager: ChatManager = {
            let chatManager = ChatManager()
            chatManager.onMessageChanged = { [weak self] (message) in
                guard let sSelf = self else { return }
                sSelf.delegate?.chatDataSourceDidUpdate(sSelf)
            }
            chatManager.changeUIMessageByID = { [weak self] (id) in
                guard let sSelf = self else { return }
                guard let uiID = sSelf.messageDataDictionary[id] else { return }
                let message = sSelf.messages[uiID]
                message.status = .success
                sSelf.delegate?.chatDataSourceDidUpdate(sSelf)
            }
            return chatManager
        }()

    }
```

I tried to make like. But it doesn't work.

```
chatManager.didLeaveConversation = { [weak self] in
            self = nil
        }
```

Comment: I see no reason to think that the leak has anything to do with the code you showed. You should use instruments to find out what is causing the CharDataSource to be retained.

Comment: Or use Xcode 8's "Debug Memory Graph", which finds where those strong references are even more easily, IMHO. But I don't understand your intent of `chatManager.didLeaveConversation = { [weak self] in self = nil }`. The `self` refers to `ChatDataSource`, not `ChatManager`. If your intent was to remove `chatManager` instance, you might want `chatManager.didLeaveConversation = { [weak self] in self?.chatManager = nil }`? BTW, is your protocol a `class` protocol? And is `delegate` a `weak` property?